# Problema com encode / decode python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt-4

Tenho 2 funções, a primeira prepara o html e grava em um arquivo .txt para que a segunda função abra esse arquivo e gere um email atraves do outlook. No corpo da mensagem, será colocado o conteúdo desse html com as devidas formatações. Tudo vai ocorrendo perfeitamente, o .txt vem com o html sem nenhum erro, mas quando o outlook está abrindo, ele é fechado e é gerado o Erro/Exception abaixo:

> 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 529: ordinal not in range(128)

Sei que esse "\xe7" é o 'ç', mas não consigo resolver, já tentei definir por .decode("utf-8") e encode("utf-8"), na variável 'email_html_leitura', mas o erro de codec persiste. Segue o código das 2 funções pra ver se fiz algo errado:

> Função 1:

```
import sys
import codecs
import os.path

def gerar_html_do_email(self):
    texto_solic = u'Solicitação Grupo '
    with codecs.open('html.txt', 'w+', encoding='utf8') as email_html:
        try:
            for k, v in self.dicionario.iteritems():
                email_html.write('<h1>'+k+'</h1>'+'\n')
                for v1 in v:
                    if (v1 in u'Consulte o documento de orientação.') or (v1 in u'Confira o documento de orientação.'):
                        for x, z in self.tit_nome_pdf.iteritems():
                            if x in k:
                                email_html.write('<a href='+'%s/%s'%(self.hiperlink,z+'>')+'Mais detalhes'+'</a>'+'\n')
                    else:
                        email_html.write('<p>'+v1+'</p>'+'\n')
                email_html.write('<p><i>'+texto_solic+'</i></p>'+'\n')
            email_html.close()
        except Exception as erro:
            self.log.write('gerar_html_para_o_email: \n%s\n'%erro)
```

> Função 2:

```
def gerar_email(self):
    import win32com.client as com
    try:
        outlook       = com.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
        mail          = outlook.CreateItem(0)
        mail.To       = u"Lista Liberação de Versões Sistema"
        mail.CC       = u"Lista GCO"
        mail.Subject  = u"Atualização Semanal Sistema Acrool"
        with codecs.open('html.txt', 'r+', encoding='utf8') as email_html_leitura:
            mail.HTMLBody = """
                            <html>
                                <head></head>
                                <body>
                                    <style type=text/css>
                                        h1{
                                            text-align: center;
                                            font-family: "Arial";
                                            font-size: 1.1em;
                                            font-weight: bold;
                                        }
                                        p{
                                            text-align: justify;
                                            font-family: "Arial";
                                            font-size: 1.1em;
                                        }
                                        a{
                                            font-family: "Arial";
                                            font-size: 1.1em;
                                        }
                                    </style>
                                    %s
                                </body>
                            </html>
                            """%(email_html_leitura.read().decode("utf-8"))
        email_html_leitura.close()
        mail.BodyFormat = 2
        mail.Display(True)
    except Exception as erro:
        self.log.write('gerar_email: \n%s\n'%erro)
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar, agradeço, toda semana tenho que fazer uma tarefa maçante de criar esse email e formatar em um padrão e tudo manualmente, pois os dados são alterados a cada semana e na maioria das vezes, são muitos. Com ele, vou ganhar praticamente uma manhã inteira. Obrigado.

Comment: PAra arrumar: use Python 3.

Comment: Para entender o que está errado, leia http://local.joelonsoftware.com/wiki/O_M%C3%ADnimo_Absoluto_Que_Todos_os_Programadores_de_Software_Precisam,_Absolutamente,_Positivamente_de_Saber_Sobre_Unicode_e_Conjuntos_de_Caracteres_(Sem_Desculpas!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que o problema está no arquivo fonte não ter codificação unicode.

Você pode colocar esse trecho logo no início do seu arquivo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

Outra solução é usar python3

**#Edit:** Adicionada solução que resolveu o problema

```
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, meu arquivo já está com essa linha no inicio, inclusive, sem ela o fonte nem é compilado. Como uso algumas bibliotecas externas como o Mechanize, testei ele no python 3 e não funcionou corretamente, por isso ainda utilizo o Python 2.7.

Comment: Entendi. Você consegue gerar um exemplo bem simples isolando a parte em que ocorre o problema? Talvez um código que somente lê a entrada do arquivo e escreve em outro. Não consigo reproduzir usando somente os códigos que passou.

Comment: Para facilitar sua análise, abaixo segue o conteúdo do arquivo html.txt que é inserido na variável <!-- mail.HTMLBody --> pelo <!-- %s --> O incrível é que quando coloco o conteúdo direto em <!-- %s --> substituindo-o, o email abre normalmente sem apresentar o erro com toda a formatação perfeita. Estou pensando em colocar o conteúdo diretamente na variável em memória, mas ainda não sei como fazer isso, estou queimando os meus neurônios aqui.

Comment: `<h1>PRO240 – Mudança 1132</h1>
<p>Uma Filial relatou erro Oracle...</p>
<p>Existiam na base 2 registros na item sem indícios de que foram...</p>
<p><i>Solicitação Filial</i></p>
<h1>PAG109 – Mudança 1133</h1>
<p>Na mudança 1109 foi solicitado à Filial...</p>
<p>Foi solicitada a alteração “Data do Pagamento”...</p>
<p>O programa foi alterado para listar...</p>
<p><i>Solicitação Filial</i></p>
<h1>CAD400 – Mudança 1134</h1>
<p>Uma Filial relatou que endereço não estava sendo...</p>
<p>O campo foi adicionado e o problema foi resolvido...</p>
<p><i>Solicitação Filial</i></p>`

Comment: Para testar, crie o arquivo html.txt e copie esse conteúdo para ele salvando como 'UTF-8' e não unicode. Rode somente a função gerar_email.

Comment: Consegui executar sem o erro trocando 
`%(email_html_leitura.read().decode("utf-8"))`
por:
`%(email_html_leitura.read())`

Comment: E abriu o outlook com a formatação correta?

Comment: Como eu reduzi bastante o html para você inserir no arquivo html.txt, pode ser que tenha dado certo por isso, mas vou testar em casa mais tarde, tomara que dê certo. Me lembro de não ter colocado o `.decode("utf-8")`, testado e dado o mesmo erro, mas posso ter feito da forma errada, só testando novamente. Valeu por estar me ajudando **klaus**.

Comment: Talvez você esteja salvando o arquivo .txt em um formato distinto de utf-8. Também pode ser que isso resolva: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: Deu certo klaus, acessei o link que você postou e coloquei logo abaixo do `import sys` a linha: `reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')` e então funcionou perfeitamente. Muito obrigado irmão, valeu d+++. posta lá essa solução pra eu dar os créditos pela sua ajuda. Abraços.